# nodejs async request stop working but no mistake

Tags: node.js

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = 30;
var count = 0;

var urlArr = ['url1','url2'.......] // ten thousand links to request

async.eachLimit(urlArr, 30, iterator, function(err) {
    console.log('complete');
});

function iterator(url,callback) {
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(count++);
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            return callback(null);
        } else{
            return callback(null);
        }

    });
}
```

The code above stop working after a few minutes, no error happen, the process is hoding and not exit, what's the problem with it?

Comment: Did you try disabling the use of an agent or setting `maxSockets` to `Infinity` ?

Comment: How to disabling the use of an agent?

Comment: I setting maxSockets to Infinity, still stop working.

Comment: You can disable agent usage by [setting `pool: false`](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/c3da3de0b0ed9d5c2c545c67de33809b85643a03/request.js#L477-L478): `request({url:url,pool:false}, function(err, response, body){...})`

Comment: I disable agent usage, still stop working.